# How to read a directory and know the files type?

Tags: node.js, fs

If we want to read a folder, we can:

```
const fs = require('fs')

let folderName = 'Any_folder_name'

fs.readdir(folderName,(err,files)=>{
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(files)
    // this is a files' name list in this folder
})
```

but the return value is only a list of files name. Such as `['README.md','src']`.

But I want to konw which is a file and which is a folder. How to do this?

I know we can use a loop to this list and `fs.stats` to confirm which is a folder.

But I want to know if there is a more effcient way to do this?

Comment: NodeJS version?

Comment: You can use `{withFileTypes: true}` options, the result will contain [fs.Dirent](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) objects. If `node >= 10.0.0`

Comment: @AyushGupta 8.7.0, and problem is solved by anther comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `{withFileTypes: true}` options, the result will contain [fs.Dirent](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dirent) objects.

Try:

```
fs.readdir(folderName, {withFileTypes: true}, (err, files) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    files.forEach(file => {
        console.log(file.isDirectory());
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **files** string array couldn't you look for the file extension and determine that.

Comment: OP asks `But I want to know which is a file and which is a folder.`

Comment: some files may have a empty extension.

Comment: also, some folders may have `.` in the name

Comment: Yes. A valid point. @saltfish, could you after using the solution provided by ihor and reply with the performance was it efficient than using stats.